# Is there a way to always have bootstrap create child rows for some of my elements?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

Here is what I'm looking to do:

[image: What I'd like to have]

The image above displays exactly what I'd like, however I'd like it to display like that permanently, not just on certain devices.  Essentially I'm looking to create a child row that contains 1-3 pieces of data.  I tried to look at DataTable's method, but, if I'm being honest, the Javascript was over my head.

Here is my code so far:

```
<table id="query" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed center-table dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="display:none">
    <thead>
        <tr class = "info">
            <th>Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 2</th>
            <th>Header 3</th>
            <th>Header 4</th>
            <th>Header 5 </th>
            <th>Header 6 </th>
            <th>Sub-header 1 </th>
            <th>Sub-header2 </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Value 1</td>
                <td>Value 1</td>
                <td>Value 1</td>
                <td>Value 1</td>
                <td>Value 1</td>
                <td>Value 1</td>
                <td>Sub Value 1</td>
                <td>Sub Value 2</td>                
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

What I'd like to have is the sub-header and sub values to always display when the user clicks '+'.  I'm also open to any other suggestions that would help achieve this as well, even if it's a link to a tutorial.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is Bootstraps' Collapse-Elements.
Have a look here to learn about them:
[Bootstrap-Collaps](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp)

I think, that they are exactly what you want.

Comment: I saw this while I was attempting to get this working, but apparently I failed miserably at setting it up correctly.  I currently have it "working" except that it expands above my table, rather than below.  I know this is because I don't have it wrapped in a <tr></tr> - but wrapping it in <tr></tr> starts throwing Uncaught TyperErrors.  I'll have to keep playing with it.

Answer (score 0):

I still think [jQuery DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html) is best way to do this.

> I tried to look at DataTable's method, but, if I'm being honest, the Javascript was over my head.

Here's a **DataTable's method *for Dummies***. ;)

**Step 1**:  Let's create a template view to which our table will contain all data.

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th> <!-- expand/collapse .details-control header column -->
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

```
td.details-control {
    background: url('../resources/details_open.png') no-repeat center center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

tr.shown td.details-control {
   background: url('../resources/details_close.png') no-repeat center center;
}
```

Notice we don't have the `<tbody></tbody>` in there. This because we will be generating it from our JavaScript code. So, let's get to it.

**Step 2:** Let's give our sub-section a look and feel.

```
function format ( dataObject ) {
  return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
      '<tr>'+
          '<td>Full name:</td>'+
          '<td>'+dataObject.name+'</td>'+
      '</tr>'+
      '<tr>'+
          '<td>Extension number:</td>'+
          '<td>'+dataObject.extn+'</td>'+
      '</tr>'+
      '<tr>'+
          '<td>Extra info:</td>'+
          '<td>And any further details here (images etc)...</td>'+
      '</tr>'+
  '</table>';
}
```

So we are passing a `dataObject` to our function. `dataObject` is basically a data structure... carrying the values on the columns of the row clicked.

**Step 3:** (a.k.a The fun part) We'll populate the table and add an event listener for when a user clicks on a row.

In the `$('document').ready(function() {...});`

- Populate the table with data - by binding our table object to the DataTable object; fetching data from the server and filling it in.

  ```
  var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
     "ajax": "../ajax/data/objects.txt",
     "columns": [
         {
             "className":      'details-control',
             "orderable":      false,
             "data":           null,
             "defaultContent": ''
         },
         { "data": "name" },
         { "data": "position" },
         { "data": "office" },
         { "data": "salary" }
      ],
      "order": [[1, 'asc']]
   } );
  ```
- The event listener - checks whether the sub-section is shown and toggles its view.

  ```
  // Add event listener for opening and closing details
  $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function() {
      var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
      var row = table.row( tr );

      if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
         // This row is already open - close it
         row.child.hide();
         tr.removeClass('shown');
      }
      else {
         // Open this row
         row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
         tr.addClass('shown');
      }
    });
  });
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the in depth explanation, I really appreciate it.  One question, I'm currently using a SQLite database for my data, is this method still possible?  I'm using Flask in Python, so all of my items are being passed to this page. I suppose I could convert the data to JSON perhaps.

Comment: @ChadD Yeah! I believe it should. This `"ajax": "../ajax/data/objects.txt"` in **Step 3** could call that python script on your server. The python script does all what has to be done, like query the `db.sqlite`, bundle-up the data and do like a `json_response`. (I have done a bit of Django, but definitely don't consider myself a python guy)